# Remove Specific Indices From 2D Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have a set of data that's of shape (1000,1000) and I know that the values I need from it are contained within the indices (25:888,11:957), how would I go about separating the two sections of data from one another?

I couldn't figure out how to get np.delete() to like the specific 2D case and I also need both the good and the bad sections of data for analysis, so I can't just specify my array bounds to be within the good indices.

I feel like there's a simple solution I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you want to divide the array?

```
In [364]: arr = np.ones((1000,1000),int)                                        
In [365]: beta = arr[25:888, 11:957]                                            
In [366]: beta.shape                                                            
Out[366]: (863, 946)
In [367]: arr[:25,:].shape                                                      
Out[367]: (25, 1000)
In [368]: arr[888:,:].shape                                                     
Out[368]: (112, 1000)
In [369]: arr[25:888,:11].shape                                                 
Out[369]: (863, 11)
In [370]: arr[25:888,957:].shape                                                
Out[370]: (863, 43)
```

I'm imaging a square with a rectangle cut out of the middle.  It's easy to specify that rectangle, but the frame is has to be viewed as 4 rectangles - unless it is described via the mask of what is missing.

Checking that I got everything:

```
In [376]: x = np.array([_366,_367,_368,_369,_370])                              
In [377]: np.multiply.reduce(x, axis=1).sum()                                   
Out[377]: 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your original numpy array is `my_arr`

**Extracting the "Good" Section:**

This is easy because the good section has a rectangular shape.

```
good_arr = my_arr[25:888, 11:957]
```

**Extracting the "Bad" Section:**

The "bad" section doesn't have a rectangular shape. Rather, it has the shape of a rectangle with a rectangular hole cut out of it.

So, you can't really store the "bad" section alone, in any array-like structure, unless you're ok with wasting some extra space to deal with the cut out portion.

**What are your options for the "Bad" Section?**

**Option 1:**
Be happy and content with having extracted the good section. Let the bad section remain as part of the original `my_arr`. While iterating trough `my_arr`, you can always discriminate between good and and bad items based on the indices. The disadvantage is that, whenever you want to process only the bad items, you have to do it through a nested double loop, rather than use some vectorized features of numpy.

**Option 2:**
Suppose we want to perform some operations such as row-wise totals or column-wise totals on only the bad items of `my_arr`, and suppose you don't want the overhead of the nested for loops. You can create something called a numpy masked array. With a masked array, you can perform most of your usual numpy operations, and numpy will automatically exclude masked out items from the calculations. Note that internally, there will be some memory wastage involved, just to store an item as "masked"

The code below illustrates how you can create a masked array called `masked_arr` from your original array `my_arr`:

```
import numpy as np

my_size = 10       # In your case, 1000
r_1, r_2 = 2, 8    # In your case, r_1 = 25, r_2 = 889 (which is 888+1)
c_1, c_2 = 3, 5    # In your case, c_1 = 11, c_2 = 958 (which is 957+1)

# Using nested list comprehension, build a boolean mask as a list of lists, of shape (my_size, my_size).
# The mask will have False everywhere, except in the sub-region [r_1:r_2, c_1:c_2], which will have True.
mask_list = [[True if ((r in range(r_1, r_2)) and (c in range(c_1, c_2))) else False 
                    for c in range(my_size)] for r in range(my_size)]

# Your original, complete 2d array. Let's just fill it with some "toy data"
my_arr = np.arange((my_size * my_size)).reshape(my_size, my_size)

print (my_arr)

masked_arr = np.ma.masked_where(mask_list, my_arr)
print ("masked_arr is:\n", masked_arr, ", and its shape is:", masked_arr.shape)
```

The output of the above is:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
 [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
 [70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]]
masked_arr is:
 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 -- -- 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 -- -- 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 -- -- 45 46 47 48 49]
 [50 51 52 -- -- 55 56 57 58 59]
 [60 61 62 -- -- 65 66 67 68 69]
 [70 71 72 -- -- 75 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]] , and its shape is: (10, 10)
```

Now that you have a masked array, you will be able to perform most of the numpy operations on it, and numpy will automatically exclude the masked items (the ones that appear as "`--`" when you print the masked array)

Some examples of what you can do with the masked array:

```
# Now, you can print column-wise totals, of only the bad items.
print (masked_arr.sum(axis=0))

# Or row-wise totals, for that matter.
print (masked_arr.sum(axis=1))
```

The output of the above is:

```
[450 460 470 192 196 500 510 520 530 540]
[45 145 198 278 358 438 518 598 845 945]
```